# How can I extract OPTIONS from a SELECT tag using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm writing a simple C# Windows Form app, I send it to a website, and on the website there is a Drop Down menu with options. I want to extract those options and add it to my own drop down menu on my app.

So far, I've written something like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection optionValues = curElement.GetElementsByTagName("OPTION");
foreach (HtmlElement curOptions in optionValues)
{
    string options = curOptions.InnerText.ToString();
    // store into an array
   foreach (string i in stringArray)
       combobox1.Items.Add(i)
}
```

The HTML is something like this:

```
<select id="some_values">
    <option value="O">Barack Obama</option>
    <option value="G">George Bush</option>
</select>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElementCollection optionValues = doc.GetElementsByTagName("OPTION");
foreach (HtmlElement optTag in optionValues)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(optTag.InnerText);
}
```

Hope it helps